# Visualising connectedness in topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, visualization

Recently started a topology course, I am struggling to visualise connected topological spaces in topology, I am understanding the definition when it comes to clopen subsets and disjointness, ie $[0,1) \cup (1,2]$ is disconnected.

Could someone give me a hand visualising this ( ie overlapping circles and how connectedness works in that sense) would it simply be two overlapping circles are connected if they intersect at some point?

The example I received was two overlapping circles completely shaded In apart from their intersection in the middle, $A$ and $B$ where connected but $A \cap B$ where not.

I would draw this if I knew how on here. Thanks

Comment: Connectedness is not a visually intuitive concept; path connectedness is.

Comment: It might help to take a look at spaces which are connected but not path connected. Take for instance $\{(x,\cos(\frac{1}{x})) ~|~ x \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \} \cup \{0\} \times [-1,1] \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.